# Remove space in Excel sheet in print preview

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, printing, print-preview

I have an Excel work book that has 20 columns and 700 rows. In the very first row, I have *Title* and in the 3rd row I have *Sub-Title*.

When I so a print preview, it shows correctly for page 1 but in page 2 and 3, it shows some empty spaces at the top. I know the reason for this was that the first 4 rows have some values such as title and subtitle so it take that height. But the title and subtitle are only in the very first column only. Is any possible to remove that space in 2 and 3rd page of Excel sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your data (title & subtitle) are in the first cell of the 1st and 3rd rows, the rows are still seen by Excel as entire rows. You can not get it to ignore parts of rows.

Because of the width of your sheet, by default it prints down then over. It will see the top rows as blank space and treat is as such.

The best solution is to place the title and subtitle in the header. You can then move your data to the top of the sheet to remove the blank rows.

[image]

This will allow more header options of how to handle the titles.

[image]